# How to align these two buttons, when on exists outside the context of the <form />?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<form />` with a text box, and an `<input />` button.

an example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/94sJa/

I'd like to have another button to the right of the first button, but outside the context of the form. Its sole purpose is to reload the page, so it doesn't need to be in the form. Plus, I don't want to submit a search query when the user clicks Reset, as would be the case when they click Search.

Is there an easy way for me to align the two buttons?

for the sake of it, the HTML and CSS are here also:

```
<div class="layout-fund-search-groupfactsheet">

    <form method="get" action="/uk/groupfactsheet/schroders">
        <input type="text" value="" name="Search" id="Search" />

        <input type="submit" class="button-medium" value="Search" />
    </form>

    <input type="submit" class="button-medium" value="Reset" />
</div>

.layout-fund-search-groupfactsheet
{
    padding: 10px 20px;

    border: 1px solid #E7DFD0;

    height: 20px;    
}

.layout-fund-search-groupfactsheet input[type=text]
{
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to reload the page with that button, you can well put it INSIDE the form and it would not make any problem. Just don't add a name attribute to that reload button.

The actual reloading would be done by javascript (I guess), so no problem. Like this:

```
<form method="get" action="/uk/groupfactsheet/schroders">
        <input type="text" value="" name="Search" id="Search" />

        <input type="submit" class="button-medium" value="Search" />
        <input type="button" class="button-medium" value="Reset"
                               onclick="window.location.reload()" />
</form>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fthAS/

Comment: Inline JavaScript is so *faux pas* these days.

Comment: @Stephen, I am just demonstrating it. OP can put an ID in it and do it externally or use jQuery or whatever he likes.

Answer (score 0):

place the form in a div and float it left place the reset button in its own div and also float left.

```
<div class="layout-fund-search-groupfactsheet">
    <form  style="float:left;" method="get" action="/uk/groupfactsheet/schroders">
        <input type="text" value="" name="Search" id="Search" />

        <input type="submit" class="button-medium" value="Search" />
    </form>
    <input style="float:left;" type="submit" class="button-medium" value="Reset" />
</div>
```

I know inline style is ugly but Im using to save my lazyness

Just like to give  thanks to stephen for pointing out my fail.

Comment: This concept could be accomplished by floating the form itself along with the extra input button without adding the extra `div` tags.

Comment: problem could be that the div element renders as empty in firefox, you require a element to clear especially if there is a requirement for padding on the element .layout-fund-search-groupfactsheet

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way to handle this kind of thing is to style a link to look like a submit button, that way your markup would change to this:

```
<div class="layout-fund-search-groupfactsheet">
    <form method="get" action="/uk/groupfactsheet/schroders">
        <fieldset><!-- Your Markup is invalid without this or at least a div -->
            <input type="text" value="" name="Search" id="Search" />
            <input type="submit" class="button-medium" value="Search" />
            <a href="#" class="button-medium">Reset</a>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
/* CSS */
input.button-medium { display:inline-block; /* your styles */}
a.button-medium { /* styled to look like your button */}
```

If `display:inline-block;` doesn't play with your current styles, you can easily add floats to the above context.

Comment: i would avoid the teaching of display inline due to cross browser issues!

Comment: I've never had an issue with it.  Of course, I don't support IE6 either.  I assume it probably does have an issue with it.

Comment: In fact, I concur with @RoToRa that I cannot find any reference on the interwebz of an issue with `inline-block` elements that was *actually* a problem with `inline-block`...

Answer (score 0):

put the second button within the form but change its type to "reset"

Answer (score 0):

```
.layout-fund-search-groupfactsheet form {display: inline}
```

Comment: display inline is not normaly great for cross browser compatability and problems could well arise as a result of using this method within older browsers like IE6.

Comment: Can you give a reference for that? I know IE6 has many problems, but I can't recall anything about `display: inline`.

Comment: sorry cant think of an exact example, only that i've had several problems with it, could be one that occurs if a site renders in quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the width of some elements to make it look good cross-browser but is this what you're looking for? Changed nothing in the HTML, except adding a class to the reset button.

http://jsfiddle.net/94sJa/2/